# Unable to access JSON file through shell script inside docker container

Tags: docker, shell, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container

I'm trying to populate data using REST endpoints of another container (i.e. `my-blog-container`) by creating a container (`data-loader`), for which I'm running a shell script `dataloader.sh` inside container (i.e. `data-loader`). In the shell script I'm trying to access the json file (i.e. `mydata.json`) to make the POST call in shell script while running the container.

> Basically Goal is to populate the data by spinning up the container on its
> own.

But I'm getting an error in my container:

```
Warning: Couldn't read data from file 
Warning: "mydata.json", this makes an empty
Warning: POST.
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
  data-loader:
    <<: *my-base-service
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dataloader
      args:
        IMAGE_NAME: <alpine base image>
    container_name: data-loader
    volumes:
      - $MY_PATH/config/mydata.json
```

**Dockerfile.dataloader**

```
ARG IMAGE_NAME
FROM ${IMAGE_NAME}

USER root
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add curl
COPY dataloader.sh /
RUN chmod +x /dataloader.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "/dataloader.sh" ]
```

**dataloader.sh**

```
response=$(curl -X POST "http://myblogcontainer:8080/blog/create" -H "accept: */*" -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
       -d @mydata.json)
echo ${response}
```

I want to populate the data using this json file. But unable to make it. Please help me out.

If you have any questions, please feel free to ask.
*Thanks in advance :)*

Comment: do you have a typo in your volumes list?

Comment: Nope, I don't think so.
Please share how to use the `json` file mentioned in `volumes` section into the shell script to make the `POST` call???

Comment: Where is the colon in your volume mapping?

Comment: Yup I was making mistake there too. Thanks @TheFool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the assumption that you have a colon as part of `MY_PATH`, you mount the file into /config/ but you are using a relative path in your script.

If your workdir is not /config, then your script will not find the file. To be sure you could use an absolute path.

```
-d '@/config/mydata.json'
```

In general, it is useful in these kinds of scenarios to do some debugging by entering the container interactively to poke around in the file system. Or by adding some print statements to your script to ensure your assumptions are correct.

Also note that your script is missing a shebang. The default interpreter is actually sh, so it works out, but it is good practice to add one anyway.

You probably should also double quote the variable `response` when using to prevent word splitting and globbing.

Comment: I wasn't giving the right `workdir`. Thanks for your help.